# After I click a button, why does my window freeze?

Tags: c, button, window, gtk, freeze

I have a window with button for start action. After i click the button window freeze, but I want to start spinner. It is in C language

This is the button setting.

```
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(setVPN), entry);
```

function setVPN:

```
const gchar *vpn;

    gtk_spinner_start(GTK_SPINNER(spinner)); //start spinner
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(msg), "<span foreground=\"#000000\">Probýhá změna VPN...</span>");

    vpn = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));

    char *ask; // Create system aks
    ask = malloc(30+strlen(vpn));
    strcpy(ask, "bash /bin/VPNSet/makeFile.sh ");
    strcat(ask, vpn);
    system(ask);
    free(ask);

    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(msg), "<span foreground=\"#00EE00\">Hotovo: VPN bylo změněno</span>");
    //message("Uspěch","VPN bylo změněno.");
    gtk_spinner_stop(GTK_SPINNER(spinner)); //stop spinner
    return;
```

Fucntion working OK. But spinner dont start, and first message don´t show. This action for spinner and set lable window do after return. I try to do as a new process but that alternative dont function.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK+ does its work, i.e. rendering of widgets and so on, when your code is *not* running. It's single-threaded, if your program is stuck inside `system()` there's no way for GTK+ to get CPU to do work, like drawing the spinner.

You must use asynchronuous I/O.

Also, just use [`g_strdup_printf()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf) to build the string.

Comment: A fixed-size stack buffer would impose an arbitrary limit on the length of the VPN string (whatever exactly that is). Either use a variable-length array, or continue using `malloc`...

Comment: @immibis Yeah that's why I said "suitably", but I changed it now since glib exposes a function to do that dance.